# Edittext value not being detected by PHP script to upload to Sql Server remote database

Tags: php, android, sql-server

I am developing an Android App which connectes to external SQLServer 2008 database through PHP script bearing in mind that i'm new to PHP

I am trying to insert an dynamic value (edittext value) from android to the external database via PHP script from one week but all in vain. I have managed to connect to the database through PHP script however, it's not inserting the edittext value. Apparently, it's not sending the value to the php variable from android. I have have experimented nearly every tutorial but not joy. I'm sure I'm making a mistake somewhere but can't figure out where. Any help or pointing to the right direction will be much appreciated.

PHP script (validating and inserting value in manufacturers_name and manufacturers_companies_id column)

```
if (!empty($_POST['manufacturers_name']) && !empty($_POST['manufacturers_companies_id']))
    {
        $man_Name = $_POST['manufacturers_name'];
        $man_com_id= $_POST['manufacturers_companies_id'];
        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_manufacturers (manufacturers_name, manufacturers_companies_id)";
        $sql.=" VALUES ('"._FormatStr4Qry($_POST[$man_Name])."','"._FormatStr4Qry($_POST[$man_com_id])."')";
            if ($res=sqlsrv_query($db,$sql,array(),array("Scrollable"=>'static')))
                { 
                    // successfully inserted into database
                    $response["success"] = 1;
                    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

                    // echoing JSON response
                    echo json_encode($response);
                } 
            else 
                {
                    // failed to insert row
                    $response["success"] = 0;
                    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

                    // echoing JSON response
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
            sqlsrv_close($db);
    }   
    else
        {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "fill in required fields.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
        }
```

PHP Executed:

```
{"success":0,"message":"fill in required fields."}
```

JSON Parser

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "UTF_8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF_8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

CreateNewAppliance class

```
public class CreateNewAppliance extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputManufacturersName;
String manufacturersName;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://datanetbeta.multi-trade.co.uk/tablet/writeManufacturers.php";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.createnewappliance);

    // Edit Text
    inputManufacturersName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etManName);
    // Create button
    Button btnCreateAppliance = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddNewAppliance);

    // button click event
    btnCreateAppliance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new NewAppliance().execute(inputManufacturersName.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class NewAppliance extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CreateNewAppliance.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Appliance..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        manufacturersName = inputManufacturersName.getText().toString().trim();
        System.out.println(manufacturersName);  //check if the value is being outputted

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("manufacturers_name", manufacturersName));

        Log.e("manufacturers_name",strings[0]); // check if
        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

}

Android executed:

```
05-28 10:35:01.929: I/System.out(6771): hdhdhdhdhdh
05-28 10:35:01.939: E/manufacturers_name(6771): hdhdhdhdhdh
05-28 10:35:01.994: D/ProgressBar(6771): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
05-28 10:35:01.994: D/ProgressBar(6771): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
05-28 10:35:01.994: D/ProgressBar(6771): updateDrawableBounds: right = 96
05-28 10:35:01.994: D/ProgressBar(6771): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 96
05-28 10:35:04.814: D/Create Response(6771): {"message":"fill in required fields.","success":0}
05-28 10:35:04.924: E/ViewRootImpl(6771): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting two parameters in your PHP script whereas you are only passing one parameter.

```
  if (!empty($_POST['manufacturers_name']) && !empty($_POST['manufacturers_companies_id']))
```

You need to pass the manufacturers_companies_id also as it is written now.

Test the script using a simple Http client and make sure you have everything to make it work. Then modify the android code.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for replying buddy. I have made all the necessary amendements to Android code. Could you tell me how to test the script with a "Simple" HttpClient please as i have done it before.

Comment: There are many tools that can help. soapui, postman (http://www.getpostman.com/). Do a google search and you can find plenty (http://www.google.com/#q=http%20post%20plugin)

Comment: Hi Raghu, I have managed to test it in the simple HttpClient and the script is working fine. After your suggestion, the PHP code is picking up the data but not displaying the text is the database column however the entry in the database is coming as blank with a new id. Can you tell me where i'm going wrong please :).

Comment: I don't knw PHP well but you are reading $_POST twice. $sql.=" VALUES ('"._FormatStr4Qry($_POST[$man_Name])."','"._FormatStr4Qry($_POST[$man_com_id])."')"; Previous line, remove the $_POST. You already have the values in man_Name and man_com_id. Just use it directly.

Comment: I'm sorry about being a beginner in PHP but using my initiative and your help i'm trying my best. Do you mean alter it like... $sql.=" VALUES ('"._FormatStr4Qry($man_Name)."','"._FormatStr4Qry($man_com_id).‌​"')";

Comment: Raghaaaaaavvvvv.... I followed your idea about removing $_POST from the Values statement and IT WORRRRKKKKKEDDDDDD!!!!!!!! THANKS A TRILLION dude.